# What is the difference between the two locations?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I have a recursive program. When the `printf` is used in the function, it outputs 123 and when used outside, it outputs 0123 .

```
#include <stdio.h>

fact(int);
int main()
{
    int x=3;
    fact(x);
    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
}

int fact(int y)
{
    if (y > 0)
    {
         fact(y-1);
         printf("%d",y);  
    }
    //printf("%d",y);   
}
```

I am not using both the `printf` at the same time . What difference does the location of this `printf` statement create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fact(int) is called by following sequence,

fact(3)-->fact(2)--->fact(1)--->fact(0)

The last call is fact(0). According to the implementation of fact(int), when 0 is passed in, 0 is printed if printf() is used outsite. 0 is not printed if printf() is used inside.

In fact, all the values passed into fact(int) is printed when printf() is used outsite.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `if` condition looks for the values greater than zero, it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When the `printf` outside that `IF` block is used, it gets executed even when y is 0, which is not the case for the `printf` inside the `IF` block.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say one reason you didn't see the answer yourself is because your code is sloppy.  Here are some complaints:

1. Your functions have no explicit return statements which are
   especially important for understanding recursive code.
2. system() requires stdlib, but stdlib.h isn't included.
3. system("PAUSE") is unportable and unnecessary.  Actually your code
   would not run on my system because of this. See:
   http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html
4. Your question looks like homework, so this one is the homework's fault and not yours: because n! grows so quickly, factorial functions using 'int' for the return type can only calculate n! for 1<=n<=12, which is useless.

Try this exercise: write a one-line factorial function using a single `return` and a conditional assignment.

Comment: I should add that I'm not trying to rip on you for not being perfect when you're learning to code.  My point is just: cleaner code => easier to read => fewer bugs